# sdl set native window

Tags: sdl, x11, ubuntu-10.04, linphone

friends!
I have the next problem: I want to modify the application `linphone 3.3.2`
This application uses the library `SDL`  to create the window where the video is playing. I want to modify this to NOT create the screen but i want to choose a window created by me to play the video in it.
Is there any function to select a window already created, or is there some other way to do it?
My system is Ubuntu 10.04 32bits and i use xlib to create the window and i have the ID of windows created.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a read through this to see if it helps at all - http://barbieri-playground.googlecode.com/svn/sdl/sdl-mplayer.c

Comment: Thanks!! Not exactly what I want. I want to select with dsl a window already created.